Updating a Docker Directus instance to latest version does not work
On DigitalOcean, I host 4 instances of Directus (nowadays all v10.10.4). Whenever there is an update, the first thing that happens is: nothing works. Same thing now: I wanted to update to Directus 10.11.1 … and as to be expected the system breaks, the domain returns 502.
The docs say that certain npm commands have to be executed (for DB migration):
npm update
npx directus database migrate:latest

But in order to do so I must enter the Docker shell via
docker exec -it my.domain.tld sh

Only then would I be able to execute npm commands. But since the instance is not running ever, I cannot not access the Docker shell.
What do I have to do to update my Docker instances of Directus from v10.10.4 to 10.11.1?

I will answer myself.
First of all: when updating with Docker containers, then there is no need to enter the Directus container to execute npm commands. Those are done automatically, when the update process is initiated.
Should there nevertheless be need to access the container, then this would be the command:
docker exec -it [directus-instance] sh

This opens a dedicated shell, where npm commands (and other commands as well) can be executed.
